# How to create an A record in Amazon Lightsail via Node JS code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-lightsail

I'm able to create A records manually in the AWS DNS records section.

My app involves creating a subdomain for each user. Is there any way I can create the A records using Node JS library of AWS [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)

I found the code for creating the A records using Route 53, but I couldn't find any information about creating A records dynamically in Amazon Lightsail.

Answer (score 1):

Using the AWS SDK for NodeJS you would create a `Lightsail` client, and then call the `createDomainEntry()` function, as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lightsail.html#createDomainEntry-property).